# Selecting columns using specific patterns then finding sum and ratio

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to calculate the sum and ratio values from data below. (The actual data contains more than 200,000 columns and 45000 rows (lines)).

For clarity purpose I have given only simple data format.

```
#Frame  BMR_42@O22  BMR_49@O13  BMR_59@O13  BMR_23@O26  BMR_10@O13  BMR_61@O26  BMR_23@O25 
 1      1           1           0           1           1           1           1
 2      0           1           0           0           1           1           0
 3      1           1           1           0           0           1           1
 4      1           1           0           0           1           0           1
 5      0           0           0           0           0           0           0
 6      1           0           1           1           0           1           0
 7      1           1           1           1           0           0           0
 8      1           1           1           0           0           0           0
 9      1           1           1           1           1           1           1
10      0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

The columns need to be selected with certain criteria.

The column data which I consider is columns with "**@O13**" only. Below I have given the selected columns from above example.

```
BMR_49@O13  BMR_59@O13  BMR_10@O13  
1           0           1       
1           0           1       
1           1           0       
1           0           1       
0           0           0       
0           1           0       
1           1           0       
1           1           0       
1           1           1       
0           0           0
```

From the selected column, I want to calculate:

1) the sum of all the "1"s. In this example we get value 16.

2) the number of total rows containing occurrence of "1" (at least once). From above example there are 8 rows which contain at least one occurrence of "1".

lastly,

3) the ratio of total of all "1"s with total lines with occurrence of "1"s.

That is :: (total of all "1"s)/(total rows with the occurance of "1"). 
Example 16/8

As a start, I tried with this command to select only the columns with "**@O13**"

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i~/@O13/); print ""}' $file2
```

Although this run but doesn't show up the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/@O13/) a[i];next} {f=0;for (i in a) if ($i) {s++;f++};if (f) r++} END {print "number of 1="s"\nrows with 1="r"\nratio="s/r}' file
number of 1=16
rows with 1=8
ratio=2
```

Some more readable:

```
awk '
NR==1{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if ($i~/@O13/)
            a[i]
        next
    }
    {
    f=0
    for (i in a)
        if ($i=="1") {
            s++
            f++
        }
    if (f) r++
    } 
END {
    print   "number of 1="s \
            "\nrows with 1="r \
            "\nratio="s/r
    }
' file
```

Comment: Mr Jotne, many thanks for the help. The code runs fine. But I would like to ask some explanation for better understanding. Why there is NR==1? What it does there? Next [if (f) r++]. What is the meaning of this line?

Comment: The `NR==1` is only run for first line, so its used to find what column contains `O13` and store it inn to array `a`.  Flag  `f` is set if there are at least one `1` in the row.  Then this `if (f) r++` counts the row that have at least one `1`