# Select column and print using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am repeating the same example as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084269/selecting-columns-using-specific-patters-then-finding-sum-and-ratio/29085031?noredirect=1#comment46415866_29085031). But the aspect of the question is different.

The example is as below.

```
#Frame  BMR_42@O22  BMR_49@O13  BMR_59@O13  BMR_23@O26  BMR_10@O13  BMR_61@O26  BMR_23@O25 
 1      1           1           0           1           1           1           1
 2      0           1           0           0           1           1           0
 3      1           1           1           0           0           1           1
 4      1           1           0           0           1           0           1
 5      0           0           0           0           0           0           0
 6      1           0           1           1           0           1           0
 7      1           1           1           1           0           0           0
 8      1           1           1           0           0           0           0
 9      1           1           1           1           1           1           1
10      0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

I wanted to select only few columns with certain criteria and print them out.

Like I want to select only columns "**BMR_*@O26**" and print the whole columns. (note: the * is for any number)

So I tried with this command

`awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^BMR_[0-9]+@O26/) print }' inputFile`.

Unfortunately, I don't get output as I wanted. The two columns that I wanted to print out are as below:

```
BMR_23@O26  BMR_61@O26 
1           1
0           1
0           1
0           0
0           0
1           1
1           0
0           0
1           1
0           0
```

How I could get the whole columns print out which I selected?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The (*) represent any number between 1-256. But the columns I select is based on the "@O23". I want to print out all the columns containing "@O23"

Comment: Very sorry for the typo error. The term should be "@O26". I am looking for the print out of the whole columns containing "@O26".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the regexp on just the header line to get the field number and then print those field numbers for every line:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /BMR_.*@O26/) fld[++n] = i }
{ for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%*s", (i<n?-12:1), $(fld[i]); print "" }
' file
BMR_23@O26  BMR_61@O26
1           1
0           1
0           1
0           0
0           0
1           1
1           0
0           0
1           1
0           0
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir. The code works fine. By the way I appreciate if you could explain little on the code especially the part : (fld[++n] = i } 
{ for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%*s", (i<n?-12:1), $(fld[i]); ). This may help me to understand the code better.

Comment: The first line of the script creates an array `fld` containing the field numbers from the first input line (`NR==1`) that match your RE. The 2nd line just prints the contents of each field number stored in array `fld`. The printf prints the first N-1 fields (`i<n`) in a left-aligned and padded12 char width (`-12`) and the last field (`! i<n`) left aligned with no padding (`1`) so you don't get trailing white space on each line. Google ternary operator.